# How to implement strncmp in NASM

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, strcmp, strncmp

I am trying to implement my own *strncmp* in asm. Here is the NASM code:

```
section .text

global my_strncmp

my_strncmp:
    mov rcx, 0; using rcx like counter
.next:
    cmp rdx, rcx ; i think this comparing doesn't work (i have no idea with it) 
    je .return_0

    mov dh, byte [rdi]
    mov dl, byte [rsi]

    cmp byte [rdi], 0
    je .return_0 ;string ending
    
    cmp byte [rsi], 0
    je .return_0 ;string ending

    inc rcx
    inc rsi
    inc rdi

    cmp dh, dl
    je .next ; the loop continues until the string ends 
    jl .return_1
    jg .retrun_2

.return_0:
    mov rax, 0
    ret

.return_1:
    mov rax, 1
    ret

.retrun_2:
    mov rax, -1
    ret
```

And I am using this simple C code to run NASM:

```
int main(){
    printf("%d\n", my_strncmp("string2", "string1", 3));
}
```

My *strncmp* actually works like ordinary strcmp (from C std. library), it's just not jumping to `.return_0` label from line 8 which reads `cmp rdx, rcx`.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You have a logic error (I think) that is not relevant, but this will return zero if you have identical strings up to some length.  In particular one empty string always returns 0.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/evefrb4Kz <== changed to `unsigned char`, added test for `'\0'` before `n` chars

Comment: Just so there's no confusion, how are you declaring the signature for `my_strncmp`?

Answer (score 1):

- The `cmp rdx, rcx` can't work because the rest of the code **erroneously modifies part of the RDX register** (`mov dh, byte [rdi]` and `mov dl, byte [rsi]` both touch parts of RDX).
  You don't need to use 2 registers to implement the 'compare at most' part of the task. Just decrement the 3rd argument and return equal once the count runs out.
- Don't compare the characters using the signed condition. Treat them **unsigned** using `jb` and `ja` (replacing `jl` and `jg`).

```
my_strncmp:
        xor   eax, eax        ; Remains zero throughout the loop
.Cont:  sub   rdx, 1
        jb    .EQ             ; Count ran out
        movzx ecx, byte [rsi]
        cmp   [rdi], cl
        jb    .LT
        ja    .GT
        inc   rdi
        inc   rsi
        test  cl, cl
        jnz   .Cont
.EQ:    ret                   ; RAX=0
.LT:    dec   rax
        ret                   ; RAX=-1
.GT:    inc   eax
        ret                   ; RAX=1
```

Comment: Another way to return + / 0 / - is to only compare for equal inside the loop, and sort out the return value after `cmp [rdi], cl / jne not_equal` is taken.  You could do something like `setb al` and some math on EAX (`strncmp` returns an `int` long `long`, so RAX is unnecessary), or `jb` to branch around inc vs. dec or `mov`.  Or a zero-extending load of the byte from `[rdi]` and subtract; the subtraction of two zero-extended bytes will have the correct sign (or be zero if they were equal.)

Comment: This version is closest to what the OP was originally doing, but isn't the most efficient way (even if you are limiting it to checking one byte at a time, not using SSE2 even when alignment of both strings is convenient.  Zero-extending two bytes and subtract is standard for strcmp / strncmp implemented to check more bytes at a time and find the position of the first difference.)